Surjectivity of MLP functions
Suppose that $\mathcal{F}(H,L)$ is a function class of all functions implemented by a multilayer perceptron with ReLU activation, width $H$ and depth $L$. Also, there is a set of all possible value corresponding to $k$ data points $x_1,\cdots,x_k$.
I was wondering if the map $f\in\mathcal{F}(H,L) \mapsto (f(x_i))_{i=1}^k\in \mathbb{R}^k $ is subjective in the sense that for any $u\in\mathbb{R}^k$, there is some $f\in\mathcal{F}(H,L)$ such that $f(x_i)=u_i$ for all $i$.
If yes, what should be the conditions for $H$ and $L$ to guarantee the surjectivity?
